# Требуется определить, в каком типе предложения используется...

Tags: синтаксис

... глагол "вызовут":

"Он сам сказал, что больше не придет, если только не обнаружится что-то новое и его *вызовут*."

Я определила его как придаточное условное. Правильно?

Спасибо!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В данном случае слово *вызовут* употреблено в ***придаточном условном*** (союз *если).*

Answer (score 3):

(1) Он сам сказал, (2) что больше не придет, (3)если только не обнаружится что-то новое и (4) его вызовут.

Сложное предложение с двумя видами подчинения: последовательное подчинение придаточного изъяснительного и придаточных условия, и однородное подчинение двух придаточных условия.

Comment: Что-то не стыкуется в "двух придаточных условия".  Не "услови***й***" ли?

Comment: Придаточные условия, два придаточных условия, два условных придаточных - что же у Вас не стыкуется?

Comment: "Однородное подчинение {чего?}" - родительный падеж нужен, разве нет? Здесь "придаточных" - прилагательное.  А где сучествительное? Опущено?  Тогда что такое "условия"? Определение?

Comment: Просто пытаюсь въехать в смысл, в терминологию...

Comment: Можно сказать: придаточное предложение (словосочетание) и придаточное (существительное). Придаточное условия - несогласованное определение, выраженное падежной формой существительного.

Comment: Понятно, спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Предложение можно упростить до *Он сказал, что придёт, если его вызовут*.
(То есть он придёт при условии, что его вызовут.) Ваше предложении является **придаточным условным**.